# Getting error connection refused when trying to consul connect using sidecar proxy to web

Tags: proxy, consul, sidecar

I am following this tutorial https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/connect

at the point when I ran  `consul connect proxy -sidecar-for web` it started throwing this error:

```
2020-07-26T14:30:18.243+0100 [ERROR] proxy.inbound: failed to dial: error="dial tcp 127.0.0.1:0: connect: can't assign requested address"
```

why this does not have port  assigned in his demonstration ?

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "web",
    "connect": {
      "sidecar_service": {
        "proxy": {
          "upstreams": [
            {
              "destination_name": "socat",
              "local_bind_port": 9191
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video in the tutorial shows the forth line as:

```
"port": 8080,
```

The documentation is missing that line. Not that it will matter because nothing is listening on web service so the error will persist. You can safely ignore that. I suspect your issue is that the operation `nc 127.0.0.1 9191` is failing. I address that below.

The full config should look like:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "web",
    "port": 8080,
    "connect": {
      "sidecar_service": {
        "proxy": {
          "upstreams": [
            {
              "destination_name": "socat",
              "local_bind_port": 9191
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, this isn't important for getting through this section of the lab. The instructions aren't clear but don't forget to restart web proxy `consul connect proxy -sidecar-for web` and start socat proxy `consul connect proxy -sidecar-for socat`
The last part is sorely missing from the instructions and the video.

Comment: can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/q/63662633/3311276