# why server can't find pihole.service.consul: NXDOMAIN and how can I fix this?

Tags: dns, consul, nslookup, dig, consul-health-check

I have following configuration for consul.

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "pihole",
    "Address": "192.168.0.15",
    "tags": [
      "pi"
    ],
    "port": 8165,
    "check": {
      "args": [
        "curl",
        "192.168.0.15"
      ],
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  }
}
```

using dig i get no error now,

```
$ dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 pihole.service.consul

; <<>> DiG 9.9.7-P3 <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 pihole.service.consul
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63573
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pihole.service.consul.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pihole.service.consul.  0   IN  A   192.168.0.15

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#8600(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 30 23:02:34 BST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

but when I do nslookup, i get the error `server can't find pihole.service.consul: NXDOMAIN`

```
$ nslookup pihole.service.consul
Server:     192.168.0.15
Address:    192.168.0.15#53

** server can't find pihole.service.consul: NXDOMAIN
```

I actually have a pihole running at this ip address 192.168.0.15
on the consul health check is passing.

```
2020-08-30T23:10:58.707+0100 [DEBUG] agent: Check status updated: check=service:pihole status=passing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command  `dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 pihole.service.consul` you explicitly instructed `host` to use server `127.0.0.1` and port `8600`.

Nslookup uses nameserver from your /etc/resolv.conf file and port 53 by default.

You can try

```
nslookup pihole.service.consul 127.0.0.1 -port=8600
```

Comment: Can I have multiple nameservers defined in etc hosts file?

Comment: Ginsberg , Did you meant `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Thank you, of course `etc/resolv.conv`, fixed mistype. Yes, you can you can have multiple nameservers in `/etc/resolve.conf`, but second and subsequent servers will be queried only if first nameserver fails.If two nameservers have different information, this means that one of them is misconfigured.